# Truth tables with $3$ rows of variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> $$\begin{array}{cccc}
> \textbf{X} &\textbf{Y} &\textbf{Z} & \textbf{A}\\
>  T & T & T & T\\ 
>  T & T & F & T\\ 
>  T& F& T& F\\ 
>  T& F& F& F\\ 
>  F& T& T& F\\ 
>  F& T& F& T\\ 
>  F& F& T& F\\ 
>  F& F& F& T\\ 
> \end{array}$$

I'm fairly new to truth tables so please bear with me. I was working on some truth table values and I was doing fine until I came across a truth table with $3$ rows to consider. Can you please help me figure out what expression will give the $A$ values?

Comment: I am assuming that you want a way of conjuring a formula for $A$, based on each of $X, Y,$ and $Z$.  For the general problem, I do **not** know of any algorithmic approach to simplifying/summarizing the pertinent truth tables entries.  With respect to this particular truth table, I was unable to create any elegant formula for $A$, based on $X,Y$ and $Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 3-input (4x2) Karnaugh map:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

With (X,Y) indexing the rows, and Z indexing the columns.

You should end up with two clusters of two $T$s.

Each cluster allows you to treat one of the 3 inputs as a "don't care" for that cluster (e.g. $Z$ might be a "don't care").  The AND of the two other two input variables in a cluster (e.g. maybe $X$ and $Y$), gives you the expression for the cluster, e.g. $X\cdot Y$

The OR of all of the cluster expressions gives you the overall expression.

You should end up with
$$ A = X \cdot Y + X' \cdot Z' $$
or something equivalent.